# Mysql Procedure. Update and Select

Tags: mysql, select, stored-procedures, sql-update, resultset

I have a procedure call that updates a set of data and then returns the data set for my to render. Everything works fine except that, I cant do both operations at once. If I do the update, then the procedure, won´t return any value and vice versa. I have seen some answers suggesting to use temptables but I could not find how to retrieve the dataset. I appreciate any help even if it comes to improving my query.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `prueba`(IN `idUsuario` INT)
MODIFIES SQL DATA

BEGIN

DECLARE flag INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE idNotificacion INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE cont INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE resultset CURSOR FOR SELECT id FROM notificaciones WHERE involvedA_idUsuario=idUsuario AND active=1;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

OPEN resultset;

SET @query = "SELECT * FROM notificaciones n WHERE n.id IN('null'";

the_loop: LOOP
    FETCH resultset INTO idNotificacion;
    IF done THEN
        LEAVE the_loop;
    END IF;
    SET cont = cont + 1;
    SET flag = TRUE;
    SET @query = CONCAT(@query," , " ,idNotificacion);
    UPDATE notificaciones SET active=0 WHERE id=idNotificacion;
END LOOP the_loop;

CLOSE resultset;

IF flag THEN
    SET @query = CONCAT(@query, ")");
    PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END IF;

END
```

Comment: What is this proc returning data to?

Comment: At the moment im trying it on phpmyadmin. But it should work with php.

Comment: The php code would be helpful; older mysql_ type statements won't work for this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/faqs-stored-procs.html#qandaitem-B-4-1-14

Comment: Maybe i wasnt clear at all. Yet, i dont have my php code working. Im just trying on phpmyadmin. The procedure its not actually returning anyvalue but showing the result as any other SELECT query. Thats what works fine. Its both at the same time.

Comment: actually i concatenate a string and then process it as a unique query. it returns a single resultset. The problem comes executing both UPDATE AND SELECT in the same procedure. In that case SELECT wont return it respective result set. Im currently using phpmyadmin 4.0.4. Thanks a lot.

Comment: is it posible to perform only one query with an UPDATE statement wich could also return a resultset?

Comment: @eggyal an UPDATE inside a proc shouldn't return any sort of result (or delete or insert or select ... into).  Only an unbounded SELECT would return a result to the client within a proc.

Comment: Have you tried this from the mysql command line client?  That would be the most appropriate way to know, *authoritatively*, what's actually going on here. I use this technique heavily and don't see why this isn't working.  SELECT @query to see what the dynamic sql you generated actually looks like, after running the proc, too.  The 'null' you're putting in the query doesn't make sense, also.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need a cursor? An option like this, maybe it can be useful:

```sql
/* Procedure structure for procedure `prueba` */

/*!50003 DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS  `prueba` */;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `prueba`(`idusuario` INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE `ids` LONGTEXT DEFAULT NULL;
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`id`) INTO `ids`
    FROM `notificaciones`
    WHERE `involveda_idusuario` = `idusuario` AND `active` = 1;
    IF (`ids` IS NOT NULL) THEN
        SET @`stmt` := CONCAT('UPDATE `notificaciones`
                SET `active` = 0
                WHERE `id` IN (', `ids`, ')');
        PREPARE `exec`  FROM @`stmt`;
        EXECUTE `exec`;
        SET @`stmt` := CONCAT('SELECT `id`, `involveda_idusuario`, `active`
                FROM `notificaciones` `n`
                WHERE `n`.`id` IS NULL OR `n`.`id` IN (', `ids`, ')');
        PREPARE `exec`  FROM @`stmt`;
        EXECUTE `exec`;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE `exec`;
    END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

You must be careful with [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) and the system variable [group_concat_max_len](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len).

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5a151/1)</kbd>